# Scrapy: Spider not found: eshopscrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a Scrapy project create with `scrapy startproject` 
And it have the following structure:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:eshopscrapy tools$ tree 
.
├── crawl.log
├── eshopscrapy
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── settings.py~
│   ├── spiders
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── eshopsite.py
│   │   └── eshopsite.pyc
│   └── tests
└── scrapy.cfg
```

When I execute: `scrapy crawl eshopscrapy`I get this error: `KeyError: 'Spider not found: eshopscrapy'` and I am unable to locate what the actual error is in my eshopsite spider. The code is presented below

```
class EshopsiteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "eshopsite"

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {'test': response.body }
```

The settings files should provide the start urls

Comment: The name is `eshopsite`

Comment: shouldn't be `scrapy crawl eshopsite` ? Last element is spider name,not project name.

Comment: Thank you very much